# What is the correct way to cite a book's chapter?

Tags: meaning

I asked a question [somewhere else](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/428652/255062).

> Chapter 1 of "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" by Kevin Patrick Murphy gives this figure (fig_1),

When I cite some content from a book, should I use "Chapter 1 **of** book name", "Chapter 1 **in** book name", or any other expression?

Comment: Quote the book title _first_, then specify the chapter or page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first of all quote the book's title, then the chapter or page.

For example:

> "Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" in Chapter 1/ on Page 1, it says...